# Unable to compile actionscript in Ubuntu

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, ubuntu-12.04

I followed the steps in [this page](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/02/install-adobe-flex-ubuntu/) to set up adobe flex 3 for developing with Actionscript 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

However, in the last step, when I try to compile an actionscript program by typing

> mxmlc MainTimeline.as

I get

> mxmlc: command not found

I have added the path to my flex bin folder in my .bashrc file. (When I do vim ~/.bashrc) I see

> export PATH=/opt/flex/bin:$PATH

at its end.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of Flex. I was working on Flex 3. While the tutorial in the link is of Flex 4.6. Working after I downloaded Flex SDK 4.6